# List all installed applications which dont contain certain keywords

Tags: powershell

I'm currently working on a PowerShell script to generate a txt file with a list of all installed applications without certain keywords.

```
(Get-WmiObject Win32_Product | 
    where ($_.Vendor -notcontains "Advanced") | 
    Format-List name,Vendor,Version | 
    out-string
).trim() >> AllApps.txt
```

The script above I want to list all installed applications whose Vendors dont contain 'Advanced' in AllApps.txt. However, it outputs all application and the '-notcontains' in the script doesnt work.

Can you please let me know where I was doing wrong?

Thanks for all replies in advance.

Comment: You need a script block in the `where-object {$_.Vendor -notcontains "Advanced"}` not just parentheses - or use the simple form `Where-Object Vendor -notcontains "Advanced"`

Comment: [`Win32_Product` is evil](https://gregramsey.net/2012/02/20/win32_product-is-evil/). **DO NOT** use it for enumerating installed programs.

Comment: @LotPings He also needs to change `{$_.Vendor -notcontains "Advanced"}` to `{-not $_.Vendor.Contains("Advanced")}`, b/c the `-contains` and `-notcontains` operators are for exact matches in an array, not for partial matches in a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `-notmatch` instead of `-notcontains`.

Contains / notcontains are for testing whether a thing is in a collection, e.g. `@(1,2,3) -contains 2`, not for testing whether a word is in a string.

You also need scriptblock braces `{}` around the `where {}` code, as LotPings comments.